# Use local storage instead of react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-redux

I want to store my rendered component (in **ReactJs**) into browser history of clients, but I don't want to use **Redux** for it, because it is so complicated for me.

Is any way for using local storage or cookies as alternative solution for Redux and React Routing?

**Edit:**
I need to using react route with cache rendered data, It means after route change and got back to previous page again, rendered data still remains there and no need to send request to server again! Like [this Redux example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world), But need to do it without Redux.

Thanks.

Comment: Redux is not a kind of cache system to store rendered components. Your main question is, what could be Redux alternative, right?

Comment: @IzumiSy  I'm not so familiar with Redux, So I want to prevent rendering component after route back, and want to cache them into client browser history with rendered data, like this Redux example: [link](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) , but need to do it without Redux!

Answer (score 1):

Redux is a state management, not related to cache or local storage. If you want to cache your components then you should look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Offline

You need to create manifest which will store your components in the cache.